# Android password hash

Tags: java, android, md5, sha1

I use this code in PHP to encrypt the password:

```
return sha1("kD0a1".md5("xA4".$password)."f4A");
```

Does anyone know an effective replacement for use in Android? I tried different functions for MD5 and SHA1 but in Java it always generates a different HASH than in PHP.

For example, as follows:

```
    public static String passwordHash(String password) {
        return sha1("kD0a1"+md5("xA4"+password)+"f4A");
    }

    public static String md5(String s) {
        try {
            MessageDigest digest = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            digest.update(s.getBytes());
            byte messageDigest[] = digest.digest();

            StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
            for (int i=0; i<messageDigest.length; i++)
                hexString.append(Integer.toHexString(0xFF & messageDigest[i]));

            return hexString.toString();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }

    public static String sha1(String clearString) {
        try {
            MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
            messageDigest.update(clearString.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            byte[] bytes = messageDigest.digest();
            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
            for (byte b : bytes) {
                buffer.append(Integer.toString((b & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
            }
            return buffer.toString();
        }
        catch (Exception ignored) {
            ignored.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

However, PHP and Java will return a different HASH string to me.

```
PASS: test
PHP: 17bf2c08f4b9447cf8316736e13833316d3edc23
JAVA: 8434696e252b89af0db033eb255c88a91a42ce14
```

However, if I enter "passTest" for example, it will generate a hash correctly

```
PASS: passTest
PHP: db4aedf1d4072b7b645996394aa74743f14eeb7a
JAVA: db4aedf1d4072b7b645996394aa74743f14eeb7a
```

And "passwordTest" is wrong again.

```
PASS: passwordTest
PHP: 1ad47c24d556187f1de5db66ff623bbe08a27f33
JAVA: 0f058b3aea48e69c028a7ee2693a98d6074b10a8
```

I can't explain that sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't, and at the same time it just changes the String for the password.

Do you think there could be a problem with coding or something? I thought TextView did it, but even if I enter a String outside of TextView, it behaves the same way.

Thank you in advance for any advice.

I would add that I am testing on SDK 31

M.

Comment: Make sure when you call `getBytes` you do it with the same encoding, e.g. `getBytes("UTF-8");` and use the same character encoding in PHP. You're not doing that with MD5

Comment: "I use this code in PHP to encrypt the password" -- that does not encrypt a password. It hashes it twice, with fixed salts, using insecure hash functions. "I tried different functions for MD5 and SHA1 but in Java it always generates a different HASH than in PHP" -- perhaps you should take it one piece at a time. Start by getting your MD5 hash matching, without the salt. Then, add the salt to your MD5 hash. Then, get your SHA-1 hash matching for a simple string. Then, get your SHA-1 hash matching for your salted MD5 output. And so on.

Comment: And *then* use a proper password hashing algorithm.

Comment: But, as luk2302 suggests, you probably are better served by researching proper password hashing algorithms, ones created by security experts (scrypt, bcrypt, Argon2, etc.), and using one of those.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I forgot. For MD5, I replaced "md.digest()" with "md.digest (md5.getBytes("UTF-8"))" and now it works properly. So far, all tests have passed 100%, so hopefully everything will be fine. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: NP. I second the comments about no encryption being involved and the fact that insecure hash algos shouldn't be used. You can simplify your hex representation with `buffer.append(String.format("%02x", b & 0xFF));`

Answer (score 0):

following code may help you to achieve what you want, it's a method named hashing and salt password, furthermore, the salt method prevents the collision of passwords that have been registered on your database

```
 public static String hashPassword(String password) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
        md.reset();
        md.update(password.getBytes());
        byte[] mdArray = md.digest();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(mdArray.length * 2);
        for(byte b : mdArray) {
            int v = b & 0xff;
            if(v < 16)
                sb.append('0');
            sb.append(Integer.toHexString(v));
        }
        
        
        
        return sb.toString();
        
    }
```

here is the salt method

```
public static String getSalt() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
    byte[] salt = new byte[32];
    sr.nextBytes(salt);
    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(salt);
    
}
```

for further reading about different hashing&salting password, consult the below link, it might help you to solid your understands

https://howtodoinjava.com/java/java-security/how-to-generate-secure-password-hash-md5-sha-pbkdf2-bcrypt-examples/

NB: you should use a strong implementation to hash your password to prevent cracking